# 'Use of undeclared type XX' error happened when imported a CocoaPods framework

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Please check the image below.

[image]

Xcode did find the source file by clicking with `command` and `control` buttons pressed.
But the annoying thing here is Xcode keeping complaining `use of undeclared type`.
This is the first CocoaPods project I just published, but I failed to use the classes defined in the files.  I'm not sure whether I did something wrong in CocoaPods setting.

I've tried the following ways.
1. Clean and close Xcode then rebuild the project ... failed.
2. Just run the project directly ... failed.
3. Delete all the files in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`, clean and reopen Xcode then build ... failed.

Methods above always help me solve problems like this when using Cocoapods, but obviously not this time.

Feel free to give any advice.
Use following `Podfile` if you need to test.
Thanks.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target ‘PopoverMuneTest’ do
    pod 'JSPopoverMenu', '~> 1.0.1' 
end
```

[podspec](https://github.com/DevNewbee/JSPopoverMenu/blob/master/JSPopoverMenu.podspec)

**Edit:**
These two files are the same as the GIF above. It Shows the error messages and Xcode do find the source file by click the class name with command and control button pressed while the error still exist.
[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]

**Edit:**
If you want to check the error yourself, add following code to your view controller after you installed the `JSPopoverMenuView` by CocoaPods.

```
class ViewController: UIViewControler {
      var menu: JSPopoverMenuView!
      var baseView: UIView { return view }
      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          menu = JSPopoverMenuView(height: 120, data: ["aaa", "aaa", "aaa"])
          menu.delegate = self
      }
}
extension ViewController: JSPopoverMenuViewDelegate {
    func popoverMenu(_ popoverMenu: JSPopoverMenuView, newTag value: String) {
        print(value)
    }
    func popoverMenu(_ popoverMenu: JSPopoverMenuView, updatedData data: [String]) {
        print(data)
    }
    func popoverMenu(_ popoverMenu: JSPopoverMenuView, didSelectedAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the name of your project?

Comment: Could you please edit your question.  The video moves too quickly to see what the first screen looks like.

Comment: Try build workspace, (you opened the Workspace, right?!)

Comment: @MartinMuldoon JSPopoverMenu [Github](https://github.com/DevNewbee/JSPopoverMenu`)

Comment: @Yitzchak yeah, of course.

Comment: @MartinMuldoon Sorry for that, I've updated it.

Comment: Post _code_, not images of code.

Comment: @matt Please check the last update.

Comment: Why is your ViewController Class subclassing UIViewControoler?  Is that a typo?

Comment: @MartinMuldoon Yeah, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Post _real_ code. Copy and paste from your project into the question. Post code. Not pictures. Not typed garbage. Code.

Comment: This is the demo project. That's all in the `ViewController.swift`. What else do you need to test a framework from CocoaPods. I've post `podfile` and Github address. Go away if you don't want to offer your think and your help.

Comment: Well.  I don't know what to tell you.  I can't load that pod:
[!] Unable to find a specification for `JSPopoverMenu (~> 1.0.1)`

Comment: @MartinMuldoon Thanks anyway. But you could try ` pod install --repo-update`. I can assure you that podfile is the same one I used to install.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.  I think I figured it.

Answer (score 0):

JsW,

I managed to get that pod installed.  I believe the issues that we are both having is related to the fact that there is no JSPopoverMenuView type.  I went into the pod itself and noticed there was a JSPopoverMenu, yet no JSPopoverMenuView class.

Additionally, a source of confusion stems from the fact that the owner of the project was in the middle of updating the Pod as we were in our back and forth.  He just updated it two hours ago.  Please note the change in class names that he just introduced.  I believe this should resolve your issues:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but my project name is `PopoverMuneTest`.  I showed it in the `podfile` in my answer.

Comment: Bad news, the owner of the project is me. I found the same thing you got. So I tried to update the class name. I thought that would work, but it failed again. Really upset. It's mid night in my country, I' will try something else tomorrow. Thank you for what you did. Have a good day or night :)